# Google Workspace Gmail add-on Store Listing Rejected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail

I am trying to publish a google workspace gmail addon to google workspace market place. I followed following steps to it.
https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish

First three steps have completed  and I am stuck on Store Listing since it was rejected.

I did not received any feedback email from Google. Some one help to ged rid of this?

Comment: Your question has no details on why our were rejected, what your application does or the scopes your application uses.

Comment: @JohnHanley I also donot know why its is rejected. I am using following scopes. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"